# Node JS Axios seperating data

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, discord.js

Im trying to separate my data so it can all fit individually in their own discord MessageEmbed fields for a corona info command for my discord bot. This is my first time legitimately doing anything with axios and i cant seem to figure out how to separate variables in the way i was wanting. help is greatly appreciated.

output:

```
[
  {
    confirmed: 3912421,
    recovered: 1344997,
    critical: 48974,
    deaths: 270065,
    lastChange: '2020-05-07T23:29:58+02:00',
    lastUpdate: '2020-05-07T23:30:02+02:00'
  }
]
```

Code:

```js
const axios = require("axios");
const Discord = require("discord.js");
var http = require("https");


module.exports = {
name: 'covid',
description: 'covid info',
},
 module.exports.execute = async(message, args) => {



var options = {
    "method": "GET",
    "hostname": "covid-19-data.p.rapidapi.com",
    "port": null,
    "path": "/totals?format=json",
    "headers": {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "covid-19-data.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key": "key removed"
    }
};

var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
    var chunks = [];

    res.on("data", function (chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
    });

    res.on("end", function () {
        var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
//var apiResult = JSON.stringify(body.toString());
let api2 = JSON.parse(body.toString());

        console.log(api2);
//console.log(data);
message.channel.send(api2);
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle('CORONA-19 WORLD STATS')
.addFields(
//{ name: 'Confirmed:', value:  api2[0]},
        //{ name: 'Recovered:', value:  api[1]},
        //{ name: 'Critical:', value: api2[2], inline: true },
        //{ name: 'Deaths:', value: api2[3], inline: true },
)
message.channel.send({embed});
    });
});

req.end();


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first snip that you have showing the array with object in it, is that how the data looks like as it's coming back to you? if yes, how would you like it to look like?

Comment: yes. it does look like that. Ideally i want it to go into the value areas of the embed fields

Comment: I apologize if I'm stating the obvious, but that's an array of Objects, so by referring to the array at it's position array[0], you can then refer to the key you're looking for.  
array[0].confirmed will return 3912421.

Comment: that works for the first one but not the others. unless i am doing something basic wrong. the rest list as undefined

Comment: when you say the rest, I'm thinking your array ends up with multiple objects in it.  this being the case you'll have to iterate over the array which can be done in a few ways. (for loop/.forEach).  in most cases your final output will look like [{},{},{},....], each of those objects will need to be accessed by incrementing your array pointer dataArray[0], dataArray[1]....please reply with how you're accessing the subsequent objects in that array.

Comment: with 2 set up it gets error  `Cannot read property 'confirmed' of undefined`

Comment: what is dataArray.length? perhaps there is no 2...

dataArray.forEach(rec => console.log(rec))....let's see what comes back.

Comment: it appears to be the args. only [0] exists

Comment: were you expecting to have more than 1 obj returned?

Comment: please elaborate what you mean by "is there more tat are supposed to provide...".

do you mean are there more objects that are supposed to be returned from Axios in your dataArray?  if so, I wouldn't know, as it would differ from API/API.

Comment: yeah i just had a moment of realization that i was totaly not using my brain on the array stuff and figured it out. thanks for the help though